# How to add Webmail to Azure web app?

Tags: azure, webmail

Setting up and website with custom domain on azure is a doddle.

However, one of the rquirements is a 'Contact Us' section of on the website, where an email is sent to the web owner on their domain e.g. support@domain.com.

It seems SendGrid only provides an API to use programmatically, and not a webmail solution.

The custom domain was bought from within azure.

Any ideas how to link a webmail component to an azure web app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Azure doesn't have one of the built-in mail clients like some of the other providers, but since a lot of the popular ones that you find are free, you could install and use one of them (one example is SquirrelMail).  Before I went that route, though, I would consider other options because your Azure website also does not have an include email host.

Does whoever you're building the website for already have their own email?  If so, then you would just send to that account and they will check their email as usual.  If not, you need to be looking at hosting options such as O365, Rackspace, or one of many other available providers.